No me deja actualizar los datos del formulario en blazor
Estoy intentando actualizar los datos de un formulario pero por alguna razón, estos no se actualizan y se quedan con los anteriores, estoy usando blazor, por alguna razón que desconozco cuando cambio los distintos parámetros del formulario, al enviarlo siguen saliendo los anteriores, no se si puede ser por el data binding de blazor o porque recoge los datos del coche con el método de getInfoCoche
Este es mi HTML
<EditForm Model="@cocheInfo" FormName="cocheEdit" OnSubmit="EditarCoche" class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="Matricula" class="form-label">Matricula</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="cocheInfo.Matricula" type="text" class="form-control" id="matricula" placeholder="Matricula"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="Marca" class="form-label">Marca</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="cocheInfo.Marca" type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" placeholder="Marca"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="Modelo" class="form-label">Modelo</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="cocheInfo.Modelo" type="text" class="form-control" id="modelo" placeholder="Modelo"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="itv" class="form-label">Proxima ITV</label>
        <InputDate @bind-Value="cocheInfo.FechaProxITV" class="form-control" id="itv" placeholder="Proxima ITV"></InputDate>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="gps" class="form-label">GPS</label>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="cocheInfo.GPS" id="gpsState" class="form-select">
            <option value="true">Si</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="destAmb" class="form-label">Dest. Ambiental</label>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="cocheInfo.DestAmbiental" id="destAmbState" class="form-select">
            <option value="0 Emisiones">0 Emisiones</option>
            <option value="ECO">ECO</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="co2" class="form-label">Tasa CO2</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="cocheInfo.TasaCO2" class="form-control" id="co2" placeholder="Tasa CO2"></InputNumber>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="consumo" class="form-label">Consumo Medio</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="cocheInfo.ConsumoMedio" class="form-control" id="consumo" placeholder="Consumo Medio"></InputNumber>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <label for="obsVe" class="form-label">Observaciones del Vehículo</label>
        <InputTextArea @bind-Value="cocheInfo.Observaciones" class="form-control" id="obsVe"></InputTextArea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar Cambios</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Limpiar Formulario</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

Y estos los métodos con los que trato
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int idCoche { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private Datos.Entidades.Coche cocheInfo { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        cocheInfo = new Datos.Entidades.Coche();
        await getInfoCoche();
    }

Este lo utilizo para recoger el coche que hemos seleccionado

    public async Task getInfoCoche() {
        var respuesta = await http.GetAsync($"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Coche/GetCocheByID?IDCoche={idCoche}");
        var rest = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        try {
            cocheInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datos.Entidades.Coche>(rest);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error al cargar el coche: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

Y este para editarlo
    public async Task EditarCoche() {
        var respuesta = await http.PutAsJsonAsync($"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Cliente/EditarCoche?Id={idCoche}&matricula={cocheInfo.Matricula}&marca={cocheInfo.Marca}&modelo={cocheInfo.Modelo}&IdCliente={id}&FechaProxITV={cocheInfo.FechaProxITV.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}&observaciones={cocheInfo.Observaciones}&GPS={cocheInfo.GPS}&DestAmbiental={cocheInfo.DestAmbiental}&tasaCO2={cocheInfo.TasaCO2}&ConsumoMedio={cocheInfo.ConsumoMedio}", cocheInfo);

        if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            navManager.NavigateTo("/Vehiculos/" + id);
        } else {
            string errorMessage = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}

Gracias por la ayuda:)!

La respuesta era incluir una simple línea de código en la parte superior del componente
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))
